# Is that possible to have two separate angular version in same project

Tags: angularjs, http

I'm cording new project and I want to call same method in which written angular older version.these are in same project but its written as two separate project.

- Main Project

  - project01

    - js

      - SaveService.js (AngularJS v1.3.15)
  - project02

    - js

      - app.js (AngularJS v1.6.2)

Now I want to call from project02 app.js for http request which written in  project01 saveservice.js.

When I call that method I got this error "TypeError: $http.post(...).success is not a function"

I can't replace `.success` to `.then` because my project01 work fine so any solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Create a service in project01 that will return your desired result rather that calling from project 02 and yes it's possible to have two different versions of angular in two different projects until they are compatible with each other.

Comment: its already create as service and its return only boolen values

Answer (score 0):

U can use that `SaveService.js`, there is no problem if that service is used with another angular version as long as their dependencies are not deprecated in current version.

Comment: but I got this error "TypeError: $http.post(...).success is not a function"

Comment: That seems to be a problem, with new versions `$http` service has changed. My wrong!